# Why doesn't this example from the pgfplots manual compile?

Tags: pgfplots, errors, examples

I copied this example from page 134 of the [`pgfplots` manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf) (version 1.12.1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[small,view={0}{90}]
    \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,patch type=bilinear,
        mesh/color input=explicit]
    coordinates {
        (0,0,0) [color=blue] (1,0,0) [color=green]
        (0,1,0) [color=yellow] (1,1,1) [color=red]
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But when I tried to compile it, I got this error message:

```
Package pgfplots Error: CRITICAL: shader=interp: got unsupported
pdf shading type '0'. This may corrupt your pdf!.

See the pgfplots package documentation for explanation.
```

For what it's worth, I get this error when compiling several of the other examples in the same section (Two/Three Dimensional Plot Types).

I am using MacTeX-2015, and TeX Live Utility shows no updates are available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code from the manual's examples works fine. Yours fails because you have lost a blank line:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}% 134
    \begin{axis}[small,view={0}{90}]
    \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,patch type=bilinear,
        mesh/color input=explicit]
    coordinates {
        (0,0,0) [color=blue] (1,0,0) [color=green]

        (0,1,0) [color=yellow] (1,1,1) [color=red]
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: plot]